# Check if the variable is empty

Tags: php

What I want is to check if the columns `$campo01` and `$campo02` are empty or not, if not empty it displays on my page, the problem is that if a variable is empty it does not display the result of the variable that is not empty

```
class Test extends URLDynamic
{

    public function Testando( $campo01, $campo02, $linguagem, $audio )
    {
         $CRUD = new CRUD;
         $this->SetParametro();

         $VerificaAudio = $this->SelectDados(
            "campo01, campo02",
            "table_01",
            "WHERE mCat = ? AND mSlug = ? AND mStatus = ?",
            array ( $this->SepURL[0], $this->SepURL[1], 1 )
         );

         foreach ( $VerificaAudio as $VerificouAudio ) {

             $campo01   = $VerificouAudio['campo01'];
             $campo02   = $VerificouAudio['campo02'];

             if ( empty ( $campo01 ) ) {
                 echo 'Empty Campo 01';
             } elseif ( empty ( $campo02 ) ) {
                 echo 'Empty Campo 02';
              } else {

                 // Returns the value of each column.
                 echo $linguagem;

                 $Temporadas = $this->SelectDados(
                    "*",
                    "table_02",
                    "WHERE mCat = ? AND mSlug = ? AND tAudio = ? AND tStatus = ?",
                     array ( $this->SepURL[0], $this->SepURL[1], $audio, 1 )
                  );

              } // end else
         } // end foreach
    }
}


$Test = new Test;
$Test->Testando( "Legendado", "Legendado" ); // campo01
$Test->Testando( "Dublado", "Dublado" ); // campo02
```

Comment: [`php` has `isset`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) to check whether a variable is declared and having value other than null.

Comment: @mehid, your question is confusing. What is your expected result based on your example above? What is it doing incorrectly based on your example above?

Comment: But your code is always show Empty text ??

Comment: @blupointmedia 
I simulated that the variables `$Test01` and `$Test02` are columns from the database, I want to check if any of these columns are empty, return an "Empty" message and show the contents of the next one.

Comment: @Mahesh Bhatnagar 
There will be cases where the column will be empty and the other column will not be empty

Comment: OK, so you want to check each variable individually then. This will return true on the first variable and the elseif and else will never get called.

Comment: If one have empty and other is not empty then show result ?? You want ??

Comment: @blupointmedia How could you do this check?

Comment: if ( empty ( $this->Teste01) && empty (  $this->Teste02 ) ) {
            print $HTML = 'Empty';
         } else {
           echo "Result"; ,}

Comment: @mehid, are you expecting to get the response from both variables?

Comment: @Mahesh Bhatnagar 
Let's say the column Test01 has the value Notices, shows the news, and the column Test02 is empty, shows the message "Empty" makes these checks on both columns and shows their contents.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Test
{
    public $Teste01;
    public $Teste02;

    public function Testando($Param01, $Param02)
    {
        $this->Teste01 = '';
        $this->Teste02 = 'Has value';

        echo $this->checkIfEmpty($this->$Param01);
        echo $this->checkIfEmpty($this->$Param02);
    }

    private function checkIfEmpty($var)
    {
        if (empty($var)) {
            return 'Empty';
        } else {
            return $var;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If I follow this logic, I will have to pass two parameters `public function Testing ($Test01, $Test02)` what would the verification look like?

Comment: I updated the answer to use two params and a private method to check each one to remove redundancy.

Comment: There is a problem, it cannot be ternary checking, because the return will be HTML element and called in database

Comment: The ternary doesn't matter. If it is empty it will return the string Empty and if not it will return whatever is in the variable.

Comment: @mehid, if my answer worked for you can you kindly make it your accepted answer? If not, please let me know and I will work with making it meet your expectations.

Comment: It won't work because the `checkIfEmpty()` method can't have a ternary check, because the `else` return will be a call to the database and HTML elements, so I can't do that inside the `$this->checkIfEmpty()` method.

Comment: @mehid, I updated and removed the ternary and added in if/else statement. Does this work for you?

Comment: @ blupointmedia It doesn't work, because I can't make the database call within the set method, this check has to be within the Test class. 
I will edit the question

Comment: Are you making a connection to the database or do you already have a connection and just need to read from a query of results? Can you give an example of your code in reference to your db call you are referring to, please?

Comment: I put the most explained example

Comment: @mehid, if $campo01 is empty and $campo02 is empty do you want to print Empty and if both have a value you want to perform the query, correct?

Comment: Not quite, without both having value displays the contents of each, now if $ field01 is not empty and $ field02 is empty displays the content of $ field01 and $ field02 displays the empty message and vice versa